# (CSS image sprite) why should I use background-position property?

Tags: css, background-position

Actually, I thought background property in css is very easty to learn.

But now image sprite is annoying me.

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
    background-image: url("../../Images/tulip.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    color:#665544;
    padding:20px;
}
</style>
 <body>
    <h1>Planting Guide</h1>
    <h2>Magnolia</h2>
    <p>some long text</p>
 </body>
```

In this case, the background-position property is used to describe from where

the background-image should be displayed. It is quite easy to understand.

```
<style type="text/css">
a.button{
    height:36px;
    background-image: url("../../Images/button-sprite.jpg");
    text-indent:-9999px;
    display: inline-block;
}
a#add-to-basket{
    width:174px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
a#framing-options{
    width:210px;
    background-position: -175px 0px;
}
a#add-to-basket:hover{
    background-position: 0px -40px;
}
a#framing-options:hover{
    background-position:-175px -40px;
}
a#add-to-basket:active{
    background-position: 0px -80px;
}
a#framing-options:active{
    background-position: -175px -80px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <a class="button" id="add-to-basket">Add to basket</a>
    <a class="button" id="framing-options">Framing options</a>
</body>
```

But in this code, background-position is used to display a part of the image.

I don't understand why and how??? I understand background cannot move to bottom

or right because a tag is not so big as body tag.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

but w3schools says background-position sets the starting position of a background image. That doesn't say this property can display a part of image.

Can somebody explain me?

Comment: it displays just a part of the background image because the rest is cut off by the container boundaries.

Comment: @ZoltanToth am i thinking right? The left upper corner's coordinate is 0px 0px. The left and upper coordinates from the left upper corner's coordinate have negative pixels. These parts will never be displayed on the screen. That's why the window displays a part of image. Am I thinking right? I am really sorry for my poor english

Comment: they're not displayed _not_ because of negative coordinates of several parts of the image (you can set the background position to negative values), but because just a small part of the background image is visible in your button. Try to play around with the values of the background position in your developer console and see how the background changes.